# How to use a SQL Delimiter through powershell

Tags: mysql, database, powershell, delimiter

Im trying to read in an sql file to be executed by powershell.  Everything works fine except that powershell throws an error due to the word delimiter. 
So my question is how would I go about using a delimiter in my sql file (I can only make minor changes to the sql file, its code must remain relatively unchanged) but loading it correctly through powershell.

Heres my code from both files and the error I get.  Thank you in advance.

Powershell:

```
$sql = (Get-Content $pwd\NewClient.sql) | Out-String
$cmd.CommandText = "USE $dbname"
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$cmd.CommandText = $sql
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

SQL:

```
delimiter //
......
end;//
delimiter ;
```

Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Delimiter //
create trigger stop_time_insert after insert on stops' at line 1"

Comment: Can you send the SQL code?  Also, I don't think the use statement will have any effect on the second call to ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but how might I send you the code?  I did a quick search and found that SO does not have a PM option.  Should I simply paste the code here?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question the first time.  I would guess that the problem has to do with the line terminator between the two systems.  My guess is that mysql is picking up "delimiter // create trigger . . ." on one line, causing the syntax error.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell doesn't support the Delimiter keyword, but it's not actually necessary in this case.

Your

```
create trigger stop_time_insert after insert on stops 
begin
   //do stuff
end;
```

block will work without the delimiter, since Powershell treats the entire command as a single item, instead of how the MySQL command line interface treats it as a multiline set.

So just remove the Delimiter statements and you should be fine. (Tested against local machine here.)

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is a very old thread, but I think it's the only one covering this topic.  The answered solution works, but you cannot use the same script when running from a MySQL command prompt.  I created a PS function as follows:

```
function executeScript([MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]$conn, [String]$filePath)
{
    $fileName = Split-Path $filePath -Leaf
    Write-Host "Executing $fileName script"
    $sqlText = Get-Content $filePath | Out-String
    $sqlText = $sqlText.Replace("DELIMITER","-- DELIMITER")
    $sqlText = $sqlText.Replace('$$',";")
    return Invoke-MySql -sql $sqlText -connection $conn | Out-Null
}
```

Assume a SQL script as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
....
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Invoke-MySql is from Mike Shepard's MySQLLib package.

Now the same script file can be executed from both environments.

Comment: Thanks for a more general (although a bit hacky) solution!